# Update the image in Cloudinary after editing it using the API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cloudinary

I have a web application in Vue.js 3. I have a component where I render images and provide the option to edit them using the Cloudinary Media Editor. However, whenever I try to achieve it, I encounter an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'upload')

This function receives the event from Cloudinary after the user finishes editing the image:

```
async handleSaveImageEdit(event) {
  
// Organize data to pass to the updateImageCloudinary function

  const res = await updateImageCloudinary({
    path: secure_url,
    folder,
    transformation,
    public_id,
    shouldReplace: true,
  })

  console.log('res:', res)
  // Rest of the function
},
```

event object looks like this:

```
event = {
  assets: [ {
   downloadUrl: 'downloadUrl',
   secureUrl: 'secureUrl,
   url: 'url,
  } ],
  transformation: 'transformation string of the changes the user have done'
}
```

Then it goes to this function in another file:

```
import cloudinary from 'cloudinary-core'

const updateImageCloudinary = async ({ path, folder = '', transformation = '', public_id = '', shouldReplace = false }) => {
    const cloudinaryCore = new cloudinary.Cloudinary({ cloud_name: 'CLOUD_NAME' })

    const options = {
        folder: folder,
        overwrite: shouldReplace,
        raw_transformation: transformation,
        resource_type: 'image',
    }

    if (shouldReplace) {
        options.public_id = public_id
    }

    try {
        let result = await cloudinaryCore.uploader.upload(path, options)
        return result
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        throw error
    }
}

export default updateImageCloudinary;
```

As I mentioned before, the error you're encountering in this function is:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'upload').

I have already ensured that I receive all the required properties as intended, and the Cloudinary cloud name is also correct.

Comment: The uploading of assets using [Cloudinary SDK is done on the server side (see this doc ref](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/backend_sdks]. Alternatively, you may upload your assets to your Cloudinary Media Library account using the [direct call to the REST API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#uploading_with_a_direct_call_to_the_rest_api) - see [example here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/cld-signed-upload-examples?path=signed-uploads%2Fpublic%2Fjs%2Fuploadclientform.js%3A1%3A0).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @espasos_573, assets can only be uploaded using the Cloudinary SDK on the server side. You can check out the [Cloudinary Vue.js documentation here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/vue_quick_start) to learn more. Alternatively, you could try using the Cloudinary upload widget to upload assets to the cloud. Here is a [link](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/vue_image_and_video_upload#:%7E:text=The%20upload%20endpoint%20is%20https,the%20file(s)%20to%20upload) to the documentation.

A direct call to the Rest API, as said by @espasos_573, will also work.